# accidentally deleted the samsung apps app that I need to use for my phone and gear2 watch. how can it be reinstalled?

Tags: samsung

accidentally deleted the samsung apps app that I need to use for my phone and gear2 watch. how can it be reinstalled if it's not in Google or anywhere else?

Comment: You didn't say what device, but you can unroot and re-install the Stock Samsung Firmware: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265477   that's for the S4 adjust your search accordingly.

Comment: And just in case your reply is "I didn't root the device": in that case you most likely also didn't delete the *Samsung Apps*, as they come pre-installed, but just de-activated them (check *Settings→Apps*, "All" tab, watch out for the app in the list, and re-activate it then).